# GCC compiling error: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw-w64

I have installed gcc(i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0.

When I type at the mingw-w64 prompt : 
gcc --version

I've got the message :
gcc (i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0

When I build an object :
gcc -Wall -m64 myprogram.c

I've got the message :
sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Could anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`i686` is a 32-bit processor.  You downloaded the wrong compiler, since you got the one that produces code for a 32-bit processor.  Uninstall it, and look for an `x86_64` compiler instead.